# Is it possible to determine how may servers is connected to an anycast address?

Tags: anycast

It's possible to set up several servers with the same IP-address, on the internet,
using anycast address. Using routing protocols , the server geographical closest to you
responds to queries.

I simply wonder if it is possible to determine how many servers is connected to one IP address?

Also is it possible to find the other ip addresses for them?

Answer (score 1):

You could probably check some BGP looking-glass servers around the world and get a pretty good idea of how many endpoints are advertised for the ASN.... whether or not they are being anycasted or represent a multi-homed site is something you can't necessarily determine though.

Comment: Do you mean that this is not a solvable problem, or do you mean that this is a solvable problem but the solution is expensive? How will someone who is willing to spend resources go about figuring how many servers is connected to an anycast address?